# SciChart.js force loading animation

Tags: charts, scichart, scichart.js

Is there a way to force the loading animation for SciChart.js ?
I receive my data with an api call, but it takes some time to process the data on server side and I would like to see the loading animation until I decide that I have all my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a loading animation inside scichart.js itself, which shown while the graphics engine is initialised.

This can be themed and styled by following steps from the [documentation here](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/js/current/webframe.html#Chart%20Styling%20-%20Themeing%20of%20Wait%20Loader.html)

If you wanted to show a loading animation for longer eg while receiving data, I suggest applying your own loader over the scichart div and disabling our one. Take a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042747/loader-overlay-over-single-div#41042833) for inspiration on how